# Aumentar tempo de vida de SESSION em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, api, session

Construí uma API utilizando PHP para utiliza-la com Aplicativos.

Quando eu saio do aplicativo (sem que eu o feche ou faça logout) depois de um tempo a sessão expira impossibilitando a atividade no aplicativo e retornando erros.

Como faço para que essa SESSION não expire ou aumentar o seu tempo de vida?

Comment: Segundo o manual do PHP, assim deve ser feito! [https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php)

Comment: Espera, a sessão é do PHP, utilizado no servidor. Não utilize sessão numa API. Como fez a validação?

Comment: Sim, eu uso em aplicativo híbrido. Arquivos HTML, CSS e javascript. Fazendo a sincronização assíncrona com o AJAX. Por sua vez que estou usando o aplicativo, consigo usar a sessao pois é um id gerando, uma sessão gerada para tal "browser", porém em função de app.
Login, senha, identificadores, funcionam.
Porém como eu disse, se eu sair - demorar uns 20-30min - a sessão expira.

Comment: Entendi. Vou responder com uma forma de aumentar o tempo de sessão do PHP, mas sinceramente acho estranho essa forma de sessões com apps. Mas enfim... Veja se funciona

Comment: Obrigado, assim que responder eu tentarei.